# Cannot query the cross product of repeated fields event_params.key and user_properties.key, with daily event tables

Tags: google-bigquery

If I am undetanding, the issue is that I have two fields that need to be flattened for the query to work...Fields in question in the below are event_params.value.string_value and user_properties.value.string_value

I am able to do this correctly with a single table, but I need to span a date range of dailies and cannot get the syntax right.   Any help?

```
SELECT
  event_params.value.string_value,
  event_timestamp,
  event_name,
  user_properties.value.string_value
FROM
  (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([[kiehls-kinetic:analytics_180943775.events_],
    DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -365, 'DAY'),
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())),
WHERE
  (event_params.key = 'session')
  AND (user_properties.key = 'associate_name')

ORDER BY
  event_params.value.string_value ASC,
 event_timestamp ASC
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use legacy SQL, or can you use standard SQL for your query instead?

Comment: Have you tried With the group by clause?

And again, I would also suggest using standard sql

Comment: I am not familiar with Standard SQL yet.. what would this look like?

Comment: Could really use a sample based on my case above.  I have been trying different approaches, but I really dont know standard SQL yet

Answer (score 1):

You'd want something like this, using standard SQL:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT value.string_value
   FROM UNNEST(event_params)
   WHERE key = 'session') AS event_value,
  event_timestamp,
  event_name,
  (SELECT value.string_value
   FROM UNNEST(user_properties)
   WHERE key = 'associate_name') AS user_value
FROM
  `kiehls-kinetic.analytics_180943775.events_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 365 DAY)) AND
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE())
ORDER BY
  event_value ASC,
  event_timestamp ASC
```